Bolditalic numbers rendering larger
I'm running into an issue with fontspec, where numbers in the bold-italic style are rendered slightly larger than regular, bold, and italic. I want to fix this, because it makes my headers and numbers in general look a bit uneven. I've verified that this doesn't happen in Word or other applications, so I believe it's LaTeX that's doing it. I've looked through the font, and I can't seem to find any additional characters for lower/uppercase styles (it's a TTF, so I don't believe that's even supported)
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
1234567890 \textbf{\textit{1234567890}} \textbf{1234567890} \textit{1234567890}
\end{document}



I added the (texlive 2024) output it looks OK to me?

the characters are all shown natural size in their respective fonts: CharisSIL-Italic.ttf CharisSIL-Bold.ttf CharisSIL-BoldItalic.ttf CharisSIL-Regular.ttf

I see no difference in height in my experiment (I added a rule as a check). Likely it's a viewer issue.
